# How to specify the exact ordinals for dll exports in MinGW?

Tags: dll, mingw, dllexport, mingw32, function

I'm trying to build a DLL with MinGW and I need to augment the exports it is generating.
I need to assign specific ordinal numbers to certain exported functions.

I created a .DEF file, but I can't find the option to tell MinGW linker to use it.
 Is it even possible?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Turned out to be extremely easy.
Simply link together with the .def file like so:

```
gcc obj1.o obj2.o obj.def -shared -omylib.dll
```

All the ordinals can be listed in the .def file (ordinal @0 doesn't work though, causes a crash of ld).

Example .def file:

```
EXPORTS  
   Insert   @1  
   Delete   @2  
   Replace  @3
```

Comment: what did your DEF file contain?